# Include loader to jQuery data-table exports

Tags: jquery, datatables, export, large-data-volumes

I am using the jQuery data tables plugin to show the table fields. And also I am using buttons(Copy) to copy whole data-table, as my data-table has large set of data. It's taking little amount of time to copy it. I want to add loader while copy is happening. I am using following config:

```
new DataTable({
    dom: 'Bti',
    buttons: ['copy'],
    "deferRender": true,
    "scroller": true,
    "sScrollY": "50vh",
});
```

How to add loader when clicked on copy button. here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sujittiwari/paoep2r3/5/) of sample code.

Comment: What do you mean by "loader"? Besides that, the peculiar fiddle does not match the above code (you are using serverside and more) after a normalization it turns out a copy takes about 1 sec, do you need a loader for that?

Comment: @davidkonrad sorry it was wrong link, I have updated the link and also its only a sample of data, my actual usecase is around 5000 rows  with more than 8 columns thanks.